# Is there any simplification of $1!+2!+3!+4!...n!$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am aware that there is a formula $^nC_0 + {^n}C_1 + {^n}C_2 + {^n}C_3 + ... {^n}C_n=2^n$.

Is there any similar formula to calculate the value of $1!+2!+3!+4!...n!$?

Can this be otherwise denoted as the sum of any progression? Like a Geometric Progression, or an Arithmetico-Geometric Progression?

Comment: @kingW3 Agreed. Although, it didn't turn up when I searched for it...

Comment: Yeah the search function isn't ideal, I've used google to find this.